# What is the time complexity of the following code? in Big O notation

Tags: java, big-o

```
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) { 
        a[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
        for(j = n ; j >= 0 ; j--)
            a[j] = a[j] + a[i];
    }
```

I cant seem to properly find the time complexity of the code or convert to big O.
I know the first loops is 1 + (n+1) + 1 and i think the 2nd/3rd ones are N*(1 - (N-1) * 1)

Comment: Please indent your code sensibly.

Comment: *"I know the first loops is 1 + (n+1) + 1"* Then please forget what you know because it is wrong. The first loop iterates `n` times, so the first loop is _O(n)_. Second (outer) loop also iterates `n` times. Third (inner) loop iterates `n+1` times. So, the nested loops are _O(n²)_.

Comment: first one is O(n), second one is O(n^2)

Comment: You might find [A plain English explanation of "Big O" notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation) a useful read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The O(n) notation is the degree of the largest term in the polynomial describing the code, and describes how the time to run grows as the input size increases.

Therefore, small details such as coefficients and lower order terms are unimportant.

Since there are two nested for loops that both iterate once through the input (size n), the code is O(n^2). The single for loop is O(n) and is not the highest order term, so it is dropped.